# ¿Por qué el español es el único idioma que usa dos signos de interrogación y exclamación?

Tags: gramática, ortografía

Why is it spanish the only language that uses two question/exclamation marks? ("?¿" "¡!")?

Comment: I don't think this is strictly speaking a duplicate.  The problem is it's based on a false premise, because Spanish is not the only language to use it.

Comment: Agreed, not a duplicate, however it would be interesting to learn which other languages use both opening and closing question and exclamation marks, Voting up on that reason alone. Admittedly its only tangentially related to spanish but i cant imagine any other context in which this question may be risen. so, vote up, and mods please don't close, if you consider this appropriate =)

Comment: @hlecuanda it's admittedly used primarily in languages that are close to Spanish: Asturian, Aragonese, Catalonian, Galician, although they may be optional rather than mandatory (that's the case for the latter two, I believe).  It is also used apparently in Walay, spoken in the Philippines.